# Coreinfo reports i7-3770 CPU doesn't support EPT (aka SLAT) and VMX

Tags: virtualization, central-processing-unit

Here is the output I get when I run coreinfo:

```
Coreinfo v3.05 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Copyright (C) 2008-2012 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Note: Coreinfo must be executed on a system without a hypervisor running for
accurate results.

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             -       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
```

According to Intel the CPU does have VMX and EPT support.  Why is it not showing up in coreinfo?

Comment: Just as a note, you haven't asked a question here.  I'd assume you're wondering why there is a difference, but it's best to actually ask that.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a virtual CPU since you are running the program from inside a VM. The virtualization itself is not virtualizable, so while the physical CPU has these features, the virtual CPU presented to the VM does not.

Comment: The output comes from the host (physical) system.

Comment: Not entirely true: In some rare cases it may actually be possible to do limited virtualisation inside a VM. But that is NOT in a Windows environment so it is a bit of a moot point in this case.

Comment: @Toro: Even the host instance sees a virtual CPU created by the hypervisor.

Comment: @Tore The Hypervisor runs in BOTH the host and the guest. (Albeit with different functions depending on which instance.) And in both cases the mere presence of the hypervisor software makes it so that CoreInfo, or any software, can not reliably report the true characteristics of the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure these options are not disabled in the Bios ?

Also: You have a Hypervisor running so the output of CoreInfo may not be reliable. That warning printed by the program isn't there for nothing. I have seen it mis-report the real config on systems with hypervisors (Hyper-V, VmWare, VirtualBox) before.

Comment: All virtualization-related BIOS settings are enabled/activated.